# Improving error messages for XML compilation errors

Tags: configuration, xml

Magento is fairly protective (as it should be) regarding the display of errors. When developer mode is enabled (as it should be during development), the application allows runtime error feedback to bubble up to the user. For XML compilation errors though this feedback is fairly useless:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in [...]/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510' in [...]app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245

This results from `Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadFile()` presenting `::loadString()` with a string which cannot be parsed:

```
public function loadFile($filePath)
{
    if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
        //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
        return false;
    }

    $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
    return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
}
```

There are several potential solutions, including using `libxml_use_internal_errors`, but the calling method does not communicate the `$filePath` param, so context would be lost. One possibility would be to throw a more explicit exception:

```
public function loadFile($filePath)
{
    if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
        //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
        return false;
    }

    $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
    try{
        return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        Mage::throwException (
            sprintf(
                "%s: error parsing %s:\r\n%s",
                __METHOD__,
                $filePath,
                $e->getMessage()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This at least provides output like the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message '**Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadFile: error parsing [...]/app/code/local/Some/Example/etc/config.xml**: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in [...]/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 534' in [...]/app/Mage.php on line 594

Are there some advantages/disadvantages/alternate approaches to consider here?

Comment: I feel like a community module to improve some of these bad core error messages would be epic. The other error message that's really bad is when it can't find a given phtml.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The approach I always take is a simple one-liner:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;
```

libxml2-utils required though...

Comment: and shows false positives in the wsi files: `namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI`

Comment: Workaround: `find . -type f -not -name 'wsi.xml' -not -name 'wsdl.xml' -not -name 'wsdl2.xml' -name '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;` (feel free to edit the answer)

Comment: For config.xml: I'm a fan of `find . -type f -name 'config.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;`

Comment: @Alex I am getting the same error, do you have fix for that?

Comment: Did you try the line I posted?