# system.log errors - Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct()

Tags: magento-1.7, xml

My system.log file is filling up with the following error message:

```
2014-08-06T20:10:59+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 3: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /home/geoff/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-08-06T20:10:59+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: ﻿&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;  in /home/geoff/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
2014-08-06T20:10:59+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: ^  in /home/geoff/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173
```

I've been trawling through xml files trying to find anything that might be calling feed.php but have had no luck.  Can anyone offer any advice?  I'm running Magento 1.7.0.2.

Comment: I did see that question but haven't been able to locate any class extending 'Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed' so am not sure what to do next.

Comment: @Geoff checkout that link of the possible duplicate, follow the recommendations of disabling the module and troubleshoot from there. Good luck. SR

Comment: I'm not sure of how to use grep so have no idea which module it could be that's causing it.  What command would I need to run and where?

Comment: Grep is a command line tool to search for text within a file. Use SSH to connect to your server and search from the root of your magento installation. If you're not sure which module is causing this, go one by one until you find it. Good luck SR

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/improving-error-messages-for-xml-compilation-errors

Comment: Post a screenshot of the folder app/etc/modules to get the idea what module can cause the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I run into log messages coming from a mystery location, I **temporarily** add the following code to the `log` method in `app/Mage.php`

```
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
{
    ob_start();
    mageDebugBacktrace();
    $message .= 'Stack Track from Above Log' . "\n" . ob_get_clean();
    //...
}
```

This will append a stack trace to each log method, which will help pinpoint the exact spot in the code that's calling `Mage::log`.  Your output will look something like this

```
[1] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:247
[2] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
[3] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
[4] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272
[5] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
[6] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:919
[7] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php:43
[8] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:919
[9] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:637
[10] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:581
[11] /path/to/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml:74
[12] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241
[13] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272
[14] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
[15] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php:81
[16] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:919
[17] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555
[18] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:390
[19] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php:43
[20] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418
[21] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
[22] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:173
[23] /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[24] /path/to/magento/app/Mage.php:686
[25] /path/to/magento/index.php:91
```

This output means that the code which called `log` was in the file `path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php` at line 247.  Since that's Magento's error handler, you'd want to go to the next file (`Template.php` at line 241), etc.  Keep going until you find that method call you're looking for.

When you're done, don't forget to restore your backup of `Mage.php`.

Comment: where i get this file with log